# Какую форму глагола нужно использовать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Человек хочет уехать из страны в другую страну, произойдет это или нет — никто не знает.
Как правильно он должен сказать?

Я уезжаю со страны.
Я хочу уехать со страны.

Comment: Пользоваться поисковиком по сайту никто не запрещал.

Answer (score 2):

**Я уезжаю из страны.** Так говорят, когда решение принято окончательно и нет никаких препятствий для этого. Форма настоящего времени говорит о том, что человек уже начал оформлять документы и собираться в дорогу.

**Я хочу уехать из страны.** Это только выражения желания, о конкретных действиях речи пока нет.

Answer (score 0):

**Со страны** - абсолютно неправильно, только **из страны**.

Comment: Этому «ответу» аргументы нужны. Далеко ходить не надо, — они имеются на сайте.